# Rails ¿Cómo hago que el controlador me muestre la vista que yo quiero?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vistas

Quisiera que mi controlador al ejecutar cierta acción me visualice una vista que deseo por ejemplo:
Quisiera mostrar en una vista que YO deseo el detalle de mis libros. Tengo lo siguiente:

```
class LibroController < ApplicationController

...

def show_details(bookId)
   @book = Book.where(id: bookId)
   ¿¿¿ format.html {redirect_to  show_details :@book) ??? esto no funciona

end



/views/books/show_details.html.erb
```

Muchas Gracias!

---

Lo que deseo hacer es que si tengo en routes:

get '/libro/detalles', to: 'libros#show_detail'

En el controlador:
def show_detail

¿Còmo hago para que se vea la vista que quiero ?

Answer (score 0):

Veo algunos errores en tu lógica. Primero tienes definido

```
def show_details(bookId)
```

lo cual no parece ser un action sino un método común, ya que los actions no reciben parámetros. Luego "asumo" que estás tratando de redireccionar al mismo action con:

```
redirect_to  show_details
```

lo cual también es incorrecto, porque entrarías en un loop.

En cualquier caso, para redireccionar dentro de tu mismo controlador, debes hacer:

```
redirect_to action: :loquesea
```

Comment: Haaaa entiendo, claro lo que quiero es que mi mètodo muestre una vista que definí. pero està bien, gracias!

Comment: @MoiLink si la respuesta resolvió tu duda, no olvides marcarla como aceptada. Saludos